# SwiftUI Nested Array Struct and displaying in List

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, swiftui

I am trying to display values from a nested array / struct. Here is my struct definition:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Station
struct Station:Codable, Identifiable  {
    let id, latitude, longitude, cp: String
    let pop, adresse, ville: String
    let prix: [Prix]
    
    // MARK: - Prix
    struct Prix: Codable, Identifiable{
        let nom, id, maj, valeur: String
        
    }
}
```

Here is my code just to prove that the data is there and it works correctly.

```
List {
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        
                            ForEach (data) { item in
                            Text("id: \(item.id)")
                            Text("lon: \(item.longitude)")
                            Text("lat: \(item.latitude)")
                            
                            Text("\(item.prix[0].nom): \(item.prix[0].valeur)")
                            Text("\(item.prix[1].nom): \(item.prix[1].valeur)")
                            Text("\(item.prix[2].nom): \(item.prix[2].valeur)")
                            Text("\(item.prix[3].nom): \(item.prix[3].valeur)")
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I would like to use ForEach to display the data in the [Prix] array, because the number of items is variable.

I have tried lots of combinations of ForEach with an Id, and without but can't get this to work.

Thankyou

Comment: Have you tried a second `ForEach` for `Prix`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a nested `ForEach`.

For each `Station` in `data`, there is an array of `Prix`. You should use `ForEach` to iterate over `item.prix` so that you don't have an index out of range exception (it will create views for each `Prix` in `item.prix`)

```
List {
                    
//VStack(alignment: .leading) {                    
    ForEach (data) { item in
             Text("id: \(item.id)")
             Text("lon: \(item.longitude)")
             Text("lat: \(item.latitude)")
             ForEach (item.prix) { prix in 
                 Text("\(prix.nom): \(prix.valeur)")
             }
    }
//}
}
```